# Internal blurred shadow with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, shadows

After trying to answer [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503702/141947), and while I am pretty sure multiple things can be improved, the only point that I feel is still missing is the blurred shadow inside the circles and the bar in the picture below.

[image]
[image]

After searching a bit, it seems that there are no much questions about such *internal* shadows or *border* shadows.

Here is what I've come up with so far for the circles, but it is really messy and the result of multiples tweaks.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns.meta,shadows,shadows.blur}
% Definition of custom colors based on the initial figure of the bar by the OP
\definecolor{myblue}{HTML}{57AED1}

% Definition of custom tikz styles in order to ease readability
\tikzset{
    % Node style (Arguments : color, section number)
    sectionnode/.style={
        fill=#1,
        draw=none,
        thick,
        circle,
        text=white,
        radius=10pt,
        },
    shadowed/.style={
        preaction={transform canvas={shift={(0.2pt,-0.2pt)}},draw=myblue!50!black},
        preaction={transform canvas={shift={(0.4pt,-0.4pt)}},draw=myblue!60!black},
        preaction={transform canvas={shift={(0.6pt,-0.6pt)}},draw=myblue!70!black},
        preaction={transform canvas={shift={(0.8pt,-0.8pt)}},draw=myblue!80!black},
        preaction={transform canvas={shift={(1.0pt,-1.0pt)}},draw=myblue!90!black}},
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \path[clip] (0,0) circle (9.2pt);
    \node[sectionnode=myblue] at (0,0) {1};
    \path[shadowed] (0,0) circle (9pt);
    \draw[black] (0,0) circle (9pt);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I also tried some stuff using the `shadows.blur` library, but it does not seem to be possible to use it for this.

So my question is : could someone propose a `node` style / `path` style that could reproduce this shadow effect without using multiple `\path` and or clips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I guess I found it myself this time.

Based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24957/141947) by Andrew Stacey, I managed to regroup everything in a style using `preaction`s and `postaction`s and voilà !

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns.meta,shadows,shadows.blur}
% Definition of custom colors based on the initial figure of the bar by the OP
\definecolor{myblue}{HTML}{57AED1}

% Definition of custom tikz styles in order to ease readability
\pgfmathsetmacro{\blurshift}{0.15}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\blurwidth}{0.3}
% From https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24957/141947
\tikzset{
  repeated postaction/.style={%
    repeat postaction/.list={#1}
  },
  repeat postaction/.code args={#1/#2}{\tikzset{postaction={transform canvas={shift={(\blurshift*#1 pt,-\blurshift*#1 pt)}},draw=myblue!#2!black,line width={\blurwidth pt}}}},
    % Node style (Arguments : color, section number)
    sectionnode/.style={fill=#1,draw=white,thick,circle,text=white,radius=10pt},
    shadowed/.style={circle,text=white,clip,
        preaction={sectionnode=myblue},
        postaction={repeated postaction={1/50,2/55,3/60,4/65,5/70,6/75,7/80,8/85,9/90,10/95}},
        postaction={sectionnode=none},
    }
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \node[shadowed] at (0,0) {1};
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT** Here is an updated capable of handling the dashed bars. The major change here is that to account for the dashed lines, you have to reduce obacity of the shadows.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns.meta,shadows,shadows.blur}
% Definition of custom colors based on the initial figure of the bar by the OP
\definecolor{myblue}{HTML}{57AED1}

% Definition of custom tikz styles in order to ease readability
\pgfmathsetmacro{\blurshift}{0.15}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\blurwidth}{0.3}
% From https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24957/141947
\tikzset{
  repeated postaction/.style={%
    repeat postaction/.list={#1}
  },
  repeat postaction/.code args={#1/#2}{\tikzset{postaction={transform canvas={shift={(\blurshift*#1 pt,-\blurshift*#1 pt)}},opacity=0.5,draw=myblue!#2!black,line width={\blurwidth pt}}}},
    % Node style (Arguments : color, section number)
    sectionnode/.style={fill=#1,draw=white,thick,circle,text=white,radius=10pt},
    shadowednode/.style={circle,text=white,clip,
        preaction={sectionnode=myblue},
        postaction={repeated postaction={1/50,2/55,3/60,4/65,5/70,6/75,7/80,8/85,9/90,10/95}},
        postaction={sectionnode=none},
    },
    sectionbar/.style={preaction={fill=#1,draw=white,thick,rounded corners=2pt},pattern={Lines[angle=45,distance={6pt},line width=3pt]},pattern color=#1!70},
    shadowedbar/.style={rounded corners=2pt,clip,
        preaction={sectionbar=myblue},
        postaction={repeated postaction={1/50,2/55,3/60,4/65,5/70,6/75,7/80,8/85,9/90,10/95}},
        postaction={draw=white,thick},
    }
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \node[shadowednode] at (0,0) {1};

    \draw[draw=none,shadowedbar] (-3,-0.5) rectangle (3,-0.65);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]